# Can I be 100% certain that a PCIe x4 card will fit in a PCIe x16 slot?

Tags: pci-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a x4 PCIe mechanical work in a x16 slot in x4 mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/234713/does-a-x4-pcie-mechanical-work-in-a-x16-slot-in-x4-mode)

I know I can place a smaller card in a larger slot. But can I be 100% certain that it works? (if we ignore a broken card or broken slot)

Comment: It's slightly different though. Are there any cases where it won't work if you put a smaller card in a larger slot?

Comment: Smaller cards are intended to be used in larger slots, as part of the PCIe specification. (a 1x card can fit, and operate, in a 1x, 4x, 8x or 16x slot). I'm not sure why you think the linked question is different, he also wants to know if a 4x card will work in a 16x slot, and run at 4x. :)

Comment: Alright, this can be closed then. I though that maybe in some special cases there might be a problem.

Comment: Moreover you can get motherboards with x16 physical slots and less (x8, x4, x1) electrical connectivity.  This will also work.  Of course if you put a graphics card in such a slot the performance will be poor!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Yes**, a PCIe x4 card will function in a PCIe x16 slot.  The slot will simply use 4 of the 16 lanes available, and the card will work properly.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Physical_layer) for more details.

Comment: In the specification of the national instrument pcie 6738 (https://www.ni.com/documentation/en/analog-output-device/latest/specs-pcie-6738/specs/), on the foot note 6, you can read:"6 Some motherboards reserve the x16 slot for graphics use. For PCI Express guidelines, visit ni.com/info and enter the Info Code PCIExpress.".  Then how can we know of it will be compatible on the slot x16 on my motherboard?

Comment: it might not work:
https://superuser.com/questions/1602514/can-we-connect-pciex4-card-in-pciex16-slot/1607600#1607600